# Winmd build for a SDK using SQLite as a dependent library

Tags: windows, sqlite, uwp, windows-10-universal, winmd

I have a SDK written in C# targeting Win10 UWP apps.
It uses SQLite and works perfectly on C# client apps.

But can a C++/javascript app use my SDK with the SQLite dependency?
A winmd (windows runtime component build) would be required in case the SDK has to be UWP compatible since a UWP app can be in C#/C++/javascript/Visual basic.

I have posted this in msdn forums and they say i would need a windows runtime component for all the 3rd party dependencies for it to work.
Have already tried wrapper projects and wrapper winmd build, it does not work.
I am unable to find any winmd build for SQLite library.

Please advise on what can be done here.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Isn't [SQLite for Windows Runtime](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e) is the one that's suppose to work in Windows Runtime component?

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin : All the examples I can find are written in C#.
I cant find any example to use this in C++.
Also SQLite has a new library for Universal Windows called "SQLite for Universal Windows Platform" and its recommended to use this.
Cant find a way to use any of these.

Comment: SQLite for Universal Windows Platform will only work in normal C# UWP project, but to make your library work across languages it has to be a Windows Runtime component. And for Windows Runtime component, there is a special version of SQLite called SQLite for Windows Runtime. If you write WinRT component using this version, it's suppose to work as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried various approaches to make this project work and found some success in the following:
Following is the project structure I made along with dependencies :

Client Application (in C++):

1. Wrapper winmd library.

Wrapper winmd library (in C#): (I generate a winmd component from this project)

1. My SDK project

My SDK project (in C#):

1. SQLite Net.
2. SQLite Net Async.
3. Newtonsoft JSON.

When I build the client application, I get the wrapperlibrary.winmd file but I dont get the corresponding dlls from the 3rd party dependencies in the output directory (SQLite and Newtonsoft). So i manually copied the required dlls to the output directory of the C++ application. Now it seems to work correctly, I can verify correct usage of the 3rd party libraries and my C# code. Presently I am just trying to make the setup work as a poc and worry about the packaging later.
The issue I now face is that my SDK also has some UI elements, so essentially compiled .xbf files for the "XAML" I have.

I have asked this question in another thread to not go off main topic here.

Answer (score 0):

> But can a C++/javascript app use my SDK with the SQLite dependency?

Yes, as in msdn forums said, you will need to wrapper in WinRT component universal apps.

> Have already tried wrapper projects and wrapper winmd build, it does not work.

I don't know what blocks you, but you can refer to [Writing a SQLite wrapper component for universal Windows apps](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/07/02/writing-a-sqlite-wrapper-component-for-universal-windows-apps/), there are detailed steps you will need to follow, and samples you may have a look.

Comment: I am using SQLite Net PCL, SQLite Net Async and NewtonSoft JSON libraries in my SDK project. These libraries are in C#. The SQLite libraries provide ORM capabilities while using the wrapper you have suggested would be using raw sqls with custom parsing. 
Even if i create a wrapper WinRT build for these libraries, how do i include the actual dll of these libraries in the client C++ app?
The C++ UWP app does not allow me to add reference to these dlls although i can include the wrapper winrt build.